# How to calculate and display the average rating in a rating bar?

Tags: java, android, rating, ratingbar

I'm a beginner programmer and I am working on an app that displays items.  Users can rate an item using a rating bar and also write a comment . The rating bar has a scale too.

How can I calculate the average rating of the item and display it in a new rating bar? Any ideas?

```
RatingBar mRatingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    EditText mFeedback = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFeedback);
    Button mSendFeedback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    TextView mRatingScale = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRatingScale);
mRatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
                mRatingScale.setText(String.valueOf(v));
                switch ((int) ratingBar.getRating()) {
                    case 1:
                        mRatingScale.setText("Pretty bad");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mRatingScale.setText("Just okay");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mRatingScale.setText("Good");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        mRatingScale.setText("Very good");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        mRatingScale.setText("Amazing!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        mRatingScale.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
        mSendFeedback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mRatingBar.getRating() == 0.0 ) {
                    Toast.makeText(EventDemo.this, "Please enter a rating", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    mFeedback.setText("");
                    mRatingBar.setRating(0);
                    Toast.makeText(EventDemo.this, "Thanks for the rating", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Without any context, example code (snippets or a repo) and a general idea of how your app works it is hard for users to answer your question correctly. Please edit your question to include relevant information.

Comment: Sum all the ratings and divide the result by the total number of ratings, then use the same code that displays the user's rating to display the general rating.

Answer (score 0):

You can get each rating value using RatingBar.getRating(), sum all the values and divide it by the number of rating bars.

```
    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
RatingBar ratingBar1 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar2);

float total = 0;
total += ratingBar.getRating();
total += ratingBar1.getRating();
float average = total / 2;
```

Is this what you want? Please comment to avoid misunderstanding. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but I also want to display the average rating on a new rating bar. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private RatingBar rBar;
    private TextView tView;
    private Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
        tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGet);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int noofstars = rBar.getNumStars();
                float getrating = rBar.getRating();
                tView.setText("Rating: "+getrating+"/"+noofstars);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. The code you propose may solve the Original Poster's problem but a few sentences that outline what your proposal is would make for a more valuable answer. 
Consider editing your answer to improve it!